# Firebase Querying with 'order by' and 'where' returning null

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
var x = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Workouts')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
    .collection('allWorkouts')
    .orderBy("Date Added", descending: true)
    .where("Name", isEqualTo: workout.name)
    .limit(limit)
    .snapshots();
```

I have attached the code I am using to query data from my Firestore database. I have a field called 'Date Added' with a space. I have also added the respective index in firebase, with 'Date Added' and 'Name', both being ascending. I get an error below

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong with the query, possibly due to the space in between the 'Date' and 'Added'?

Picture of the DB below where you can see that there are entries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check following:
 1. Please share the snipped of code where you are trying to read the snapshots. 
 2. Print the value of `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid` to see if you are logged in and getting corrected `uid`. 
 3. If possible also share a screenshot of your Firestore DB which shows you actually have entries in the path you are trying to read which is : `/Workouts/<uid>/allWorkouts`

Comment: The current user is logged in because as soon as I remove the order by query, the information starts coming. Please check again I have added the DB picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the `Where` clause before the `OrderBy` clause, like this:

```
var x = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Workouts')
    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
    .collection('allWorkouts')
    .where("Name", isEqualTo: workout.name)
    .orderBy("Date Added", descending: true)
    .limit(limit)
    .snapshots();
```

Also, you mentioned that you created a `composite index` with `Date Added` and `Name` fields both `ascending`, but you are ordering `Date Added` as `descending`, try fixing that index as attached in image[image: Create composite index]

Comment: that did not work unfortunately. I have attached the image please take a look

Comment: answer edited now

Comment: Understood I will try and fix that now